# NullPointerException when mocking a DB call with Pageable and Slice Interfaces with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

**Summary**

We are trying to mock a call to DB with a Pageable & Slice objects, but the mock is not returning the assigned return value when called by the application.

**In Details**

We have a Pageable method in our `Spring-Data Repository`:

```
public interface CatRepository extends CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<Cat, String> {

  Slice<Cat> findAllByOwnerIdAndName(String ownerId, String name, Pageable pageable);
```

Since `Slice` is an interface, we created a `MockSlice` class that implements its methods:

```
@Builder
@Data
public class MockSlice implements Slice{
...
```

When creating a `Mockito` test for this call we wrote this code:

```
 Slice<Cat> slice = MockSlice.builder().content(new LinkedList()).build();
  when(catRepository.findAllByOwnerIdAndname(anyString(), anyString(), any(Pageable.class))).thenReturn(slice);
```

The test class has these annotations:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class GetCatsTest{
```

But, in the service class, when the unit test runs, the following `slice` is `null` :

```
  Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, 1000, Sort.by("id"));
  Slice<Cat> slice = catRepository.findAllByOwnerIdAndName("23423", "Oscar", pageable);
  catList = slice.getContent();  <-- NullpointetException here
```

**EDIT**

To make sure the wiring is correct, and the overall conf is working fine, I added another non-paginatable method to the repository, mocked it and it is working fine:

In Test class:

```
LinkedList<Cat> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(new Cat("fasdfasf", "Oscar"));
when(catRepository.findAllByOwnerIdAndName(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(list);
```

In repository interface:

```
List<Cat> findAllByOwnerIdAndName(String ownerId, String name);
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration for `catRepository` in your service and test? It is possible that the mock is not being injected correctly

Comment: Are you sure that the `.build()` method isn't returning `null`?

Comment: @migron , yes. `build()` is creating the `MockSlice` correctly

Comment: @EamonScullion , the `catRepository` seems to be injected OK, as other methods in it are mocked correctly.

Comment: Is it just a typo that your test uses lower case n for name in `findAllByOwnerIdAndname`?

Comment: Can you confirm what `any` library you are using?

Comment: @EamonScullion `import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;`

Comment: @riorio can't spot any issues with your code, can you provide a full example of your test so I can check that the test is performing as expected?

Comment: @EamonScullion thanks for the help. It was an Intellij bug....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending several hours on this issue....

The problem was in `Intellij` and not in the code.

Intellij  version is:

```
2018.2.3 Ultimate Edition

Build #UI-182.4323.46

Built on Sep 3 2018
```

At some point it just started to work....